# There are any equivalent "scipy.norm.norm.sf" function in R

Tags: r, function, statistics

I need to find any R function similar to scipy.stats.norm.sf or math.erfc?
Any help would be great. I am trying google, but not find any good answer yet.
Thank you for your time.
Paulo

Comment: `pracma::erfc()` and `rnorm()`?

Comment: @AndS, post your comment as an answer?  The `erfc` part of this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29067916/error-function-erfz/29068040#29068040  (that's why it's good to ask a *single* question in each Stack Overflow post ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard equivalent of `scipy.stats.norm.sf(x)` will be

```r
pnorm(x, lower.tail = FALSE)
```

The standard equivalent of `math.erfc(x)` will be

```r
pnorm(x * sqrt(2), lower.tail = FALSE) * 2
```

Comment: I found this: erfc    <- function(x) { (1 - pnorm(x * sqrt(2))) * 2} what is the same as the code you suggested. It is the function in the pracma::erfc() package. Thank you

Comment: I never used `pracma` actually. :-) The interplay between [cdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function), [pdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function), [quantile function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function), [mgf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) and [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)) is the very heart of probability theory.

Comment: Could you help to check if I am implementing my R functions correctly? I ask because I didn't have any friend who program in R to help me. It is just look at the functions and check  if I going in the right direction. my email psschlogl@gmail.com

Comment: @PauloSergioSchlogl . You are welcome. Sure. I added a [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248059) to discuss this.

Comment: For what it's worth, `pnorm(x, lower.tail = FALSE)` is slightly better than `1-pnorm(x)` (more accurate for large values of `x`)

Comment: @BenBolker, should it imply that its left tail is more precise than its right tail in R? :-)) I normally reverse the sign of `x` rather than write `1 - pnorm(x)`

Comment: You could reverse the sign too.  For symmetric distributions that trick works; R provides `lower.tail` for all distributions as a unified way to handle complementary distributions. (As you probably already know, the naive `1-pnorm(x)` calculation is subject to catastrophic floating point error/underflow for large `x`)

Comment: which x do you mean by large for this purpose? 1e3, 1e6?

Comment: Thanks. I checked: it really happens at x of approximately 8.2923. Too bad. I improved the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make sure they are 1:1 what you are looking for, but I recommend `pracma::erfc()` and `stats::rnorm()`.

Comment: I need to use it to compute the desired p-value. For example, if you have a threshold t, then the probability of getting a
z-value larger than t is
P(z > t) = erfc(t/sqrt(2))/2
and the probability of getting a z-value less than t is
P(z < t) = erfc(-t/sqrt(2))/2. I think that \2 two is due the lower and right tail right?

Comment: @PauloSergioSchlogl In statistics, people don't mess with erf or erfc functions, they usually directly use what is called a cumulative distribution function (cdf). It maps the value **x** of the random variable **X** to P(**X** < **x**). For the normal distribution, the cdf function in R is `pnorm()`. So if you want to calculate the (one-sided) *p*-value for the threshold **t**, you just write `pnorm(t)` or `1 - pnorm(t)`.

Comment: `rnorm` is not actually right.